# How to store an instance of QPropertyChangeHandler?

Tags: c++, qt, qt6

`QProperty::onValueChange()` returns a [QPropertyChangeHandler](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qpropertychangehandler.html) object which I believe should be stored as a member variable so it will not be destroyed and consequently de-registering the Functor.

Since `QPropertyChangeHandler` is a Template class that takes a Functor, I need to provide the type of Functor that I am going to use but I am not sure what type to place there.

How should I store the returned `QPropertyChangeHandler` object?

---

The following are my best attempt so far:

**Proptest.h**

```
#ifndef PROP_TEST
#define PROP_TEST

#include <QObject>
#include <QProperty>
#include <QString>
#include <QPropertyChangeHandler>
#include <functional>

class PropTest : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    QProperty<QString> m_property;

    PropTest();
    ~PropTest() = default;

    // QString m_property;

    QPropertyChangeHandler< std::function<void()> > propertyChangeHandler;

    void TestFunction();
};

#endif
```

**Proptest.cpp**

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QString>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QApplication>

#include "prop_test.h"

PropTest::PropTest() { // <- error occurs here
    this->propertyChangeHandler = this->m_property.onValueChanged(&PropTest::TestFunction);
}

void PropTest::TestFunction() {
    // further processing
}

int main(int arc, char* argv[]) {

    auto app = QApplication(arc, argv);

    auto ob = new PropTest{};

    ob->m_property = "String";
    ob->m_property = "New";

    app.exec();
}
```

---

But all I got was this unfamiliar error:

```
[build] prop_test.cpp: In constructor 'PropTest::PropTest()':
[build] prop_test.cpp:11:20: error: no matching function for call to 'QPropertyChangeHandler<std::function<void()> >::QPropertyChangeHandler()'
[build]    11 | PropTest::PropTest() {
[build]       |                    ^
```

and I find the place where the error occurs bizarre.

Comment: At first glance, you seem to have declared your member variable as taking a function with 1 `bool` parameter. Your `TestFunction` method takes to parameter so it would go in a `std::function<void()>` instead. Is this what you're asking?

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion, it must have been a typo when preparing the MRE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us proceed in order.
Disclaimer: unfortunately, I made the mistake of downloading a non-English version of Visual studio and never changed it back so I do not have the exact error messages.

---

The first error you sould have notice is in the lines of `QPropertyChangeHandler<[...]>` has no default constructor.

This is easily corrected by moving

```
this->propertyChangeHandler = this->m_property.onValueChanged(&PropTest::TestFunction);
```

out of the constructor's body and into the initialization list of your class.

---

With that error out of the way, it is time to solve the type mess.

The exact type of the `PropTest::TestFunction` method is `void(PropTest::*)()`; this is a different type from `void()` because inherently, for class' methods, the pointer `this` is always going to be an argument.

Because `this` is considered an argument, you cannot do:

```
propertyChangeHandler(m_property.onValueChanged(&PropTest::TestFunction))
```

If you try, you get the error message from Qt (from a static assert in `QProperty.h`): `Functor callback must be callable without any parameters`.

Assuming the function you want to connect in the handler needs to be an object method (not a separate function, not a static method), there are several ways to solve this:

1. First solution uses a functor, with your object as its member.
   Header:

   ```
   class PropTest;

   struct TestFunctor {
   public:
       TestFunctor(PropTest* propTestObject);
       void operator () () const;

   private:
       PropTest* object;

   };
   ```

   And source:

   ```
   TestFunctor::TestFunctor(PropTest* propTestObject)
       : object(propTestObject)
   {
   }
   void TestFunctor::operator()() const {
       object->TestFunction();
   }
   ```

   With that solution (and that solution only), the type of `propertyChangeHandler` must be changed to `QPropertyChangeHandler<TestFunctor>` and it is constructed with
   `propertyChangeHandler( m_property.onValueChanged(TestFunctor(this)))`.
2. Second solution is to use a lambda. For instance:

   ```
   PropTest::PropTest()
       : QObject(),
       propertyChangeHandler(m_property.onValueChanged(std::function<void()>([=]() { this->TestFunction(); })))
   {
   }
   ```

   The type of `propertyChangeHandler` is `QPropertyChangeHandler< std::function<void()> >` if you decide to proceed this way (i.e. same as your question).
3. Third solution is to [bind](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) the `TestFunction` method.

   ```
   PropTest::PropTest()
       : QObject(),
       propertyChangeHandler(m_property.onValueChanged(std::function<void()>(std::bind(&PropTest::TestFunction, this))))
   {
   }
   ```
4. If you can turn the class method `TestFunction()` into a separate function or into a static method, it simplifies the issue quite a bit. The type of propertyChangeHandler needs to be, respectively `QPropertyChangeHandler<void()>` (for a separate function) or  `QPropertyChangeHandler<void(*)()>` (for a static method).

And finally, it compiles!!

PS: If the function does not need to be attached to an object instance, I would use solution 4. Otherwise, I would go for either solution 2 or solution 3.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this and worked around it, as I think it cannot be done using `QPropertyChangeHandler`.

First my understanding of the error. The compiler complains about the existence of this line:

```
QPropertyChangeHandler< std::function<void()> > propertyChangeHandler;
```

not because this type of object is not allowed to exist, or is of the wrong type, but because there is no valid constructor for it; i.e. you cannot have a bare `QPropertyChangeHandler`. The error says there is no matching function for call to:

```
QPropertyChangeHandler<std::function<void()> >::QPropertyChangeHandler()
```

which is the signature of the constructor, needed to instantiate the class member. Changing the offending line to:

```
QPropertyChangeHandler< std::function<void()> > *propertyChangeHandler;
```

would solve the error at first glance (because the pointer can exist without an object), but doesn't help because we get an instance of `QPropertyChangeHandler` that will be deallocated anyway, so taking its address doesn't help much. The only way to have an instance variable of type `QPropertyChangeHandler<...>` would be to pass it to the constructor, e.g. have a `create()` function instantiate the `QPropertyChangeHandler` first and then pass it to a newly created class, using `std::move` and very precise syntax. In my case this worked, eventually, but was not a solution, as the change handler needed access to the to-be-created class instance.

The solution I ended up with, is quite simple, with a constructor like:

```
SomeClass::SomeClass() {
    notif = property.addNotifier([&](){
        stuff();
    })
}
```

and a class definition:

```
class SomeClass {
private:
    QPropertyNotifier notif;
}
```

As a bonus, `QPropertyNotifier` is not templated, so you don't need to care about the exact template arguments to use.